# Anchor links inside table widget

Tags: yii, yii-booster

Using yii-booster, I want to create a pretty simple table.  The data is completely valid and works just fine using this:

```
$gridDataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($model->results);

$gridColumns = array(
    array('name'=>'score', 'header'=>'Score'),
    array('name'=>'community', 'header'=>'Community ID'),
    array('name'=>'ip', 'header'=>'IP Address')
);

$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'type'=>'striped',
    'dataProvider'=>$gridDataProvider,
    'template'=>"{items}",
    'columns'=>$gridColumns,
));
```

But I want the ip address to show up as a anchor, such as: `<a href="steam://{ip}>{ip}</a>`, and I can't figure out how to make the data display as a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
'columns' => array(
array(
   'name'=>'date_added',
   'type'=>'raw',
    'value'=>'CHtml::link("link", array("site/index"))', 
    ),
),
```

That will create a link in each row under the header of date_added (in my example)

As your columns are done with a variable I guess yours would be:

```
$gridColumns = array(
array('name'=>'score', 'header'=>'Score'),
array('name'=>'community', 'header'=>'Community ID'),
array('name'=>'ip', 'header'=>'IP Address', 'type'=>'raw', 'value'=>'CHtml::link("$data->ip", array("controller/action", "ip"=>$data->ip))')
);
```